# What's good practice for ASP.Net MVC4 Login Sessions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently, my website stores a Session ID next to a user's entry in to the database and an IP Address, which is then stored in a cookie. If the Session ID and the IP Address match on each page then we grant them access.
This seems fine, but we want to allow people to login to the website on multiple IP Addresses/Multiple Sessions.

So I'm just wondering what the best and most secure way would be? Do we just store Username and Password in the Session, do we store Username and Hashed password in the Session or do we just store a Unique ID in a new "Sessions" table of the database with the User's ID next to it? Then do we just store the Session ID in the Cookie?

I'm not sure if Session tampering is a thing, but I usually assume it's possible by the elite so I'm trying to be as secure as possible. I know Editing Cookies is simple too.

The website uses a Web Service in the background. When a user enters their login details, they are sent to the Service and checked which then returns yay or nay. 
The reason for this is that the Service is used by multiple applications of different platforms. So the Basic/Simple Membership model won't really work here.

Comment: Please dont store passwords in any session. Plus your passwords should be hashed in the db already.

Comment: They are. All passwords are hashed and salted. Like I said, I'm a bit of a security freak. Which is why I'm doubting any ideas I can come up with. All I find on the net is people using ASP.Net's SimpleMembership, which isn't an option for me as it Auths with a service running in the background.

Comment: @Largoh - huh?  SimpleMembership does not auth with a service running in the background, not unless you're using OpenId integration, which is optional.

Comment: Sorry, I mean my Website auths with a Service, not SimpleMembership.

Comment: I see, so you mean your site uses a service for authorization,  That's still perfectly fine and can be accomplished with Membership.  In fact, you might want to consider implementing OpenID for your auth service, in which case you could use SimpleMembership.  However, you could just as easily do a custom membership provider that auths against your serice.

Comment: I'll have another look at a Custom Membership Provider. I'm relatively new to ASP.Net so when I looked before I couldn't get my head around it which I put down to us using mysql rather than mssql

Comment: @Largoh - here's an example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme

Comment: Brill, thanks. I've been following this: http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/how-to-configure-custom-membership-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4-with-external-login-like-facebook-yahoo-google-or-other-relying-party-accounts-2/ I've got it Validating fine but doesn't keep the user logged in. I'll start on it again in the morning and will look at that link you sent. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this done by following guides here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme
and here:
http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/how-to-configure-custom-membership-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4-with-external-login-like-facebook-yahoo-google-or-other-relying-party-accounts-2/

I managed to get it working with our service by overriding the required Methods from Customer Membership and making them check with our service and responding accordingly. It works great.

Example

```
    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        MyUser newUser = new MyUser 
        {
            EMail = username,
            Password = password
        };

        try
        {
            MyUser user = MyService.Authenticate(newUser);
            if (user.EMail != null && user.IsActivated)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

It also gives the ability to use MembershipCreateStatus for registering new users. Which let me really specify tiny details of why something would fail rather than just throw an error like it did previously.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Mystere Man.

Answer (score 0):

> If the Session ID and the IP Address match on each page then we grant
>   them access.

Have you considered that [IP addresses are far from secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).  Moreover, they are liable to legitimately change in a single session.

It sounds like you've rolled your own security, which can be fine if you have good experience in this area.

I would suggest you look at the security that comes out of the box with MVC, for example have a look at [oauth](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc). It should have what you need.

Comment: Indeed, when using mobile devices, the IP Address can change randomly, while the session is still in use.

Comment: This is why I want to get rid of this method. It's annoying to the user more than anything.

Comment: @Largoh - if you're truly a "security freak" like you say, you should understand that rolling your own security is almost always a bad idea unless you have a LOT of experience and know all the pitfalls you can fall into, even then experts often make mistakes, which is why the most secure code is the code that has been seen by a lot of people.  Chances are, anything you come up with will either duplicate something already done by a more mature code base, or won't be very secure.. no matter how much you think you know better.

Comment: Exactly why I came here to ask. Everything I came up with I can easily think of a way around it. Half wish I hadn't have bothered.

Comment: Don't be put off, I think it's a good idea that you're going to have a look at the security frameworks already out there.